# How to use multiple cron expressions with @scheduled annotation spring boot

Tags: spring-scheduled

**How to use multiple cron expressions within single @scheduled annotation spring boot**

I have to run same job every Monday and last day of every month , I want to achieve it using @scheduled annotation with 2 cron expressions. Is is possible and if yes how I can implement??

Comment: Struck with same issue , did u find any solution ?